# Why is the onclick function not triggering on iOS safari browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, shopify

I have a site on shopify and everything is working fine except when we use the site on iOS safari browser and click the “add to cart” button, it doesn't trigger the onclick function. It works fine for all the desktop browser and android phone browser aswell. The button just doesn’t trigger on iOS safari

Here is the snippet for the button:

```
<a onclick="cartAdd('AM',3)"><p class="icon-cart">Add to cart</p></a>
```

Comment: Code snippet is missing

Comment: <a onclick="cartAdd('AM',3)"><p class="icon-cart">Add to cart</p></a>

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm saying, use addEventListener() method instead:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: It could be something like iOS doesn’t fire a click on an anchor element without a href?

Answer (score 0):

Is the button like this?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"></button>
```

If yes, you should use:

```
button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Else I can't help you like you don't give any code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you can do is add a class to your button, and then add an event listener to it:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("addToCartBtn")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Item added to cart!")
});
```

```html
<a class="addToCartBtn"><p class="icon-cart">Add to cart</p></a>
```

Comment: is it possible to pass ('AM',3) via this method? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, like this:

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("addToCartBtn")[0].addEventListener("click", cartAdd('AM', 3))`